# How do I save a snapshot of a 3d plot using the rgl package as a pdf and not lose data

Tags: r

I want to save a snapshot of a 3d plot using the rgl package as a pdf.

I am using the code here https://r-graphics.org/recipe-miscgraph-3d-save to practice first.

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(mtcars$wt, mtcars$disp, mtcars$mpg, type = "s", size = 0.75, lit = FALSE)
```

And the 3d plot appears.
When I use

```
rgl.postscript('3dplot.pdf', fmt = 'pdf')
```

I get the 3D plot. And it prints to PDF correctly, it does have extra diagonals.

When I try with my own data with coloured points and a legend, most of my points do not print, nor does the legend.

Any ideas please?